# printf("C programming %s","is %s for health","good");

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 printf("C programming %s","is %s for health","good");
return 0;
}
```

is this a way to print c programming is good for health.
as of my idea first "is %s for health","good" will render then "c programming %s", is good for health".

Comment: You can't nest printf calls this way. Please, before just smashing around randomly, [read the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf). This is how we all learned.

Comment: you could compile it and see if it is.

Comment: C Programming is %s for health this is the output i get

Comment: I know why you asked this. This would work though `"C programming %s""is %s for health","good","bad"`

Comment: Well if the output doesn't match what you are asking if your method is viable to produce, then clearly it is not a viable way to print that string.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 printf("C programming is %s for health","good");
 printf("C programming is good for health");
return 0;
}
```

you can simply write it like any of the way in this code.
but the way you wrote is wrong because it only the first argument of `printf()`
can use %s.
all other arguments act as simple strings

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *good= "good";
    char *health = "health";
    printf("C programming is %s for %s", health, good);

    printf("C programming is %s for %s", good, health);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on 2 arguments then use `%s` for string twice.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("C programming %s%s","is good" ," for health");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
C programming is good for health
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to nest `printf` commands, you should use `sprintf`. Example:

```
char a[50] = "is %s for health";
char b[50] = "C programming %s";
char c[50], d[50];
sprintf(c, b, a);
printf("%s\n", c);
sprintf(d, c, "good");
printf("%s\n", d);
```

The output of this program will be:

```
C programming is %s for health
C programming is good for health
```

Note that when calling `sprintf(c, b, a)` the `%s` in `a` and in `b` have different roles. `sprintf`'s second arg is **format**, so %s in `b` will be the place where `a` is placed, while `%s` in `a` is just part of the string.

Also, check `snprintf` which is safer than `sprintf`.

Answer (score 0):

`printf` doesn't work like that - only the first argument is processed to recognize conversion specifiers, and the remaining arguments are formatted accordingly.

This means the `%s` in `"is %s for the health"` is not recognized as a conversion specifier - it's only recognized as part of a string.  It also means that the final `"good"` argument is ignored.

**TL/DR;** - you can't "chain" format strings like that in C.

BTW - C programming is *not* good for your health.  Trust me.